# Is "majority" an adverb as well?

Tags: word-meaning

Is "majority" an adverb as well? It seems it is indeed an adverb in the following sentence (meaning "predominantly"). However, I couldn't find the confirmation of it in Lexico or Wiktionary (it's defined as a noun only)

> Although the Donbas region was majority Ukrainian, "many ethnic Russians had moved in," Sysyn said.

*(from [here](https://www.politifact.com/article/2022/feb/23/putins-one-sided-history-ukraines-relationship/))*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "majority" is modifying the word "Ukrainian".  The word "Ukrainian" here would seem to pass the tests for being an adjective (Eg you could modify it for degree - How Ukrainian was Donbas? It was quite Ukrainian. It was more Ukrainian than Sussex.)

An adverb is a catchall category that includes modifiers of verbs, adjectives and adverbs. So "majority" is indeed an adverb in this use.

Comment: Why do you think is it not included in the dictionary?